# Android studio - how to find which library is using dangerous permission?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-permissions

I am trying to upload a apk to the google play store but its saying to my surprise that i am using  the following permission:

```
Your APK is using permissions that require a privacy policy: (android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO).
```

so i searched the entire IDE for "android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" but i cant find it.  How can i find out which 3rd party is requesting this ?  There should be a way to view in the manifest merger process all the manifest but when i hit shift twice and search manifest only the local manifest are showing up. The other is bit code and i cant view it.

Comment: Use the Manifest editor in Android Studio in the Merged Manifest tab

Answer (score 68, accepted):

In project build directory, there is a manifest merger report.

In my case, it is located under **[ProjectRoot]/app/build/outputs/logs/manifest-merger-debug-report.txt**

From this file, your can find where the permission is added. For example:

```
uses-permission#android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO
ADDED from /home/jack/AndroidProject/ApiDemos/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml:45:5-71
    android:name
            ADDED from /home/jack/AndroidProject/ApiDemos/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml:45:22-68
uses-permission#android.permission.CAMERA
ADDED from /home/jack/AndroidProject/ApiDemos/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml:49:5-65
    android:name
            ADDED from /home/jack/AndroidProject/ApiDemos/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml:49:22-62
```

Comment: Thank you @cmoaciopm +1 for working sol. you saved my day.

Answer (score 3):

**Android Studio and Permissions**

You can use `Merged Manifest`[<sup>[About]</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67812344/4770877) feature

```
Open AndroidManifest.xml -> Merged Manifest
```

Answer (score 1):

If the library is open source you can check their source code for the permissions they have used. 
They usually list the permission on their Read.me files.
Even if they are proprietary libs they will list the permissions they will be using otherwise their security is questionable.

Comment: other thing can be you application has to do something with microphone, so yo need to put the privacy policy url in app store.