# What is the Merged Manifest in Android?

Tags: android, android-studio, manifest

I am trying to understand the purpose of the Merged Manifest in the Android Studio. Which kind of Information, I can encode exploring this file. Can any one please share their views. Thanks in Advance.

[image: check the attached screenshot]

Comment: Please don't post code examples as an image. Rather [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52261267/edit) your question and add the code as clear text (formatted as code using the `{ }` button)

Comment: @derHugo, it is not actually a code example, I just shared a view of the Android Studio. I do appreciate your suggestion and if i share any code then definitely I will follow your instruction. Thanks !

Comment: I have fixed this issue just check my answer in this link. https://stackoverflow.com/a/69173658/11696949

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your APK file can contain just one `AndroidManifest.xml` file, but your Android Studio project may contain several—provided by the main source set, build variants, and imported libraries. So when building your app, the Gradle build merges all manifest files into a single manifest file that's packaged into your APK.

The manifest merger tool combines all XML elements from each file by following some merge heuristics and by obeying merge preferences that you have defined with special XML attributes.

I have included the **summary** about the **merger manifest**.

You can read more about it [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/manifest-merge#top_of_page)

Answer (score 2):

**Android Merged Manifest**

`Merge Manifest` feature allows you to check how the final manifest file will looks like. Every module, dependency etc. has it's own AndroidManifest file which is merged in compile time into single one. It allows you to find who is responsible for dangerous permissions[<sup>[About]</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67812259/4770877), who exactly brings specific android components and how they are triggered etc.